# decimal round wrong calculation

Tags: mysql, floating-point, decimal

I have the sample following numbers which are stored in an mysql db in the decimal(10,2) format

```
1499.3927125506 - 1499.39 -> this is how it saved into the database
384.41295546559 - 384.41
278.74493927126 - 278.74
537.44939271255 - 537.45
```

The actual total before saving into the database is 1700, however after the saving the total becomes 1699.99

How can I make the total 1700 NOT 1699.99?

Comment: your saving with  reduced precision, you will never get the same value if you change the precision

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a math problem, not a programming one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With numbers like that, you should use `DOUBLE`, not `DECIMAL(.., ..)`.

(Do *not* use `DOUBLE(.., ..)`; that will just add to your problems.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your [MySQL datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) to match the precision of your data if you want to avoid rounding errors. In your presented data, you will need precision (total digits) of 14 with a scale (digits after decimal) of 10 which would be `DECIMAL(14,10)` to sum perfectly to 1700.